# Can I transfer my PC characters to my Mac?

Tags: borderlands-2

I was hopeful that I'd be able to download and boot up Borderlands 2 on my mac this morning to the grand sight of all the characters I'd created on the PC version happily waiting for me. Unfortunately, that was not the case.

**Edit:** the offical word from Aspyr is that steam cloud sync between Mac and PC will not occur:
`The Steam Clouds are separate since the PC and Mac will be out of sync as far as versions are concerned.`

So, given that this doesn't happen automatically, is there a way I can copy some files from my PC (bootcamp) to my mac and keep my character progress? It's not something I want to do more than once.

Comment: BL2 has cloud... no need to copy anything.

Comment: @user28015 This did not sync between my computers on the first startup. I'll check again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this by messing around with Aspyr folder with user data on your Documents. I would love to help but I don't have the game ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. I have my characters syncing between my Mac and PC.

Comment: Via steam? Or manually?

Comment: @authenticgeek - I have my Documents/Games folder symlinked with my Dropbox folder on two different computers (both Windows).

Comment: I made the transition manually and it works fine.

Comment: OK ... I'll assume the answer is to copy (manually) or symlink (for auto updates) the SavData folder under the WillowGame folder.

Answer (score 25):

In order to sync your files you need to copy all the save files from this location in Windows:

`C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\My Games/Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\76561197975478513\`

To this location in OS X

`Users/MYNAME/Library/Application Support/Borderlands 2/WillowGame/SaveData/76561197975478513/`

Note: the folder `/76561197975478513/` may be named differently on your machine. If the Library folder is hidden in OS X, go up to Go in the menu bar, hold alt/option and Library should appear. Alternatively, click on Go to Folder and paste in the following:

`~/Library/Application Support/Borderlands 2/WillowGame/SaveData`

Comment: In Linux the game data folder is `~/.local/share/aspyr-media/borderlands 2/willowgame/savedata` (all in lowercase). Unfortunately after copying my Windows savedata to that location, the game completely ignored them.

Answer (score 2):

It does work, moving save file to and from mac and PC. Your save file on the mac may be in the user's library folder in **application support** not preferences as previously stated.

Answer (score 1):

The mac saves are, by default:

`'Users -> %username% -> Library -> Preferences -> Feral Interactive -> Borderlands -> SaveData'`

and the windows saves are, by default:

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\(Random Numbers)`

(in both cases, %username% should be replaced with your user name).

I don't know if they are compatible between mac and windows versions (I doubt it, even if they use the same naming scheme), but it may be as simple as copying the windows saves and placing them in the mac folder. If it doesn't work, you can simply remove them.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be compatible?  It's effectively the same piece of code that reads and writes the save files on both Windows and Mac (leaving aside lower level OS specifics).  You might be surprised at how much of the code base is cross platform.

Comment: I am doubtful, but I don't know either way. On the one hand: this is an Unreal engine game, so save games may be handled in a portable way. On the other hand, the mac version was ported by a different developer and there may be implementation changes which invalidate saves between versions. Things like "serialization" of program objects during the save process (if they happen at all for borderlands) could/would break compatibility AFAIK if those object definitions are altered during the porting to mac os.

Comment: That's not the correct folder for Borderlands 2 save files. The sequel is not published by Feral.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the Borderlands 2 game save file on OS X has changed to: `/Users/<User>/Library/Saved Application State/com.aspyr.borderlands2.steam.savedState/`.

The location of the save file in Windows 8.1 remains the same: `Users\<User>\Library\Application Support\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\76561198032614222\`.

I just tried copying save files from my Mac to PC to no avail. It appears the game save formats are different (Windows uses a `.bin` while Mac has a `.data` file).

Answer (score 0):

Steam Cloud saves were out of sync for the first few versions of the mac release and settings never did, and never will sync across the two platforms, due to the way in which GearBox created the settings files.  Saves on the other hand now should sync properly.

Of course, you might not want to rely on this for day to day play on two separate platforms, because sometimes the saves stop syncing when patches are applied to the game, as occasionally the Mac and Linux patches can be delayed.

If you want to create a file link on a file server or across partitions, you can link the save files from the two platforms into their appropriate place, do NOT link the entire "Borderlands 2" player settings directory, as the configuration files have slight changes between the two platforms.

Answer (score -1):

In order to copy my savegame to linux I copied them into the folder `~/.local/share/aspyr-media/borderlands 2/willowgame/savedata` and make the file `Save0001.sav` all lowercase, e.g. `save0001.sav`.

Comment: The OP is asking for Mac, not Linux.

Answer (score -3):

A more detailed explanation of what @Robotnik suggested:

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3049227

Comment: Could you please summarize that link in case it ever goes down? Then it still helps future users to this site.