# Borderlands 2 Save Converter from PS3 to Mac

Tags: borderlands-2, ps3, macos

Is there a tool that I can use to convert my PS3 saves to Mac-formatted ones? If there isn't one, is there a program I can use to "read" my PS3 save data so I can manually convert a Mac save to a duplicate of that data?

Comment: Not sure this is enough to make an answer, but here's what I turned up after a little search: Gibbed save editor for Windows does this fairly easily - just file/open and select the type of ps3 -> once open, change the type to PC and save. [PC saves transfer to MAC just fine](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93561/can-i-transfer-my-pc-characters-to-my-mac). If you lack a Windows computer, run Windows in parallels or dual boot or whatever floats your boat. This seems lengthy, but in my brief search, I did not find a mac app that does format conversion. It's a start anyway.

Comment: @skovacs1 Thanks for the answer. I'll try and run it on Wine.

Comment: @skovacs1 Wine didn't work, but a Windows VM did. Thanks! The save data files work great!