# Retrieving Steam Game progress from Mac to new PC

Tags: steam, pc, macos

I haven't specifically seen a question relating to the retrieval of saved game progress that was achieved on the Mac version of Steam to be transferred to the PC version.

I have almost 3000 hours of Borderlands 2 gameplay while on an iMac, I have cloud set up on the mac side, but don't know how to transfer that data over to the PC steam app.

There are differences in the PC vs Mac versions of the app, so if anyone has specific instructions and experience with both versions of the app and could direct me on how to transfer to the new PC I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you have a gearbox account that your save data would be transferred, but I have no way of testing that. Also if the game saves the data in a different way based on the OS, this might not be possible, because the PC version might not be able to read the save of the MAC version, but again I'm not sure so here is a comment

Comment: On the other hand, I thought Borderlands 2 uses Steam Cloud service? Have you tried to just run the game on the PC?

Comment: I have. I started playing just out of frustration, I just don't know how to retrieve the data on the PC side of things...

Answer (score 2):

This is not always possible because as others have said the Mac, Linux, and Windows versions of a game save are often of a slightly-different format. This has also already been asked and answered before [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93561/can-i-transfer-my-pc-characters-to-my-mac)

So, BL2 is a special case which does allow this, but must be done manually.

Edit: Manual instructions (since I couldn't edit the comment below fast enough -- sorry!)

The second answer on the question I linked to above covers that, but I'll summarize from their directions:

- Find the save data

Mac - Users/MYNAME/Library/Application Support/Borderlands 2/WillowGame/SaveData/SteamID64/

Windows - C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\SteamID64\

Copy the files from the one to the other to "synch" them.

---

You could setup "selective synch" with a Cloud service to make this automatic. I used to use Dropbox and it can do this, but I don't suggest Dropbox though, especially on Mac (Google Mac Dropbox exploit).

Comment: Can you explain how to do it manually?

Comment: Edited my answer to summarize the directions from the top-voted answer for the question I linked to above. Sorry about that other comment ("Find the save data") -- I wasn't trying to be sarcastic, I forgot we have to use Shift + Enter to get newlines here and just pressed enter...so it submitted the comment. Lol.